# Emitting child component data changes to parent component automatically

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have `BusinessComponent`(parent) and `AddressComponent`(child). Now within the `AddressComponent`, the two way data binding is working fine. Now I require any change in `AddressComponent` to be emitted to the `BusinessComponent` as an `Address`object, not an individual property of the `Address` object. I tried using `ngOnChanges()` but the [doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#onchanges) says this.

> Angular only calls the hook when the value of the input property changes. The value of the hero property is the reference to the hero object. Angular doesn't care that the hero's own name property changed. The hero object reference didn't change so, from Angular's perspective, there is no change to report!

And without emitting the data, the parent is detecting the changes of `AddressComponent`. I couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Here are my code samples.

**AddressComponent**

```
import { Component,  EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from '../services';
import { Address } from '../types';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-address',
  templateUrl: 'address.component.html'
})

export class AddressComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input()
    address: Address;

    @Output()
    addressChange: EventEmitter<Address> = new EventEmitter<Address>();

    constructor(
        private appService: AppService
    ) { super(appService); }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.address = new Address('');
  }
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        // This is not being called for emitting the changes.
        console.log(changes);
        this.addressChange.emit(this.address);
    }
}
```

**AddressComponent** Template

```
<div class="form-row">
     <label class="form-label" for="houseNo">{{ labels['houseNo'] }}</label>
    {{ address.houseNo }}
    <input [(ngModel)] = "address.houseNo" type="text" name="houseNo" id="houseNo" ref-houseNo>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
     <label class="form-label"  for="street">{{ labels['street'] }}</label>
    <input [(ngModel)] = "address.street" type="text" name="street" id="street" ref-street>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
     <label class="form-label"  for="village">{{ labels['village'] }}</label>
    <input [(ngModel)] = "address.village" type="text" name="village" id="village" ref-village>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
     <label class="form-label"  for="city">{{ labels['city'] }}</label>
    <input [(ngModel)] = "address.city" type="text" name="city" id="city" ref-city>
</div>
```

And I bind the input like this in `BusinessComponet`

`<app-address [(address)]="address"></app-address>`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: how your address variable is changed??

Comment: It will be changed by the user. Added the template.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. You do not need to emit any event to parent component becase parent and child use the same object reference. Just remove parenthesis from the template, modify the data at your child component, you will see that it will get modified at your parent component too.

Comment: And you have a misunderstanding about ngOnChanges method. ngOnChanges will be fired when any @Input() variable is modified from outside the component (from parent component). It won't be called in your component because you only change the property of the object, not the object itself!

Comment: @omeralper Do you mean parenthesis ( these things **( )** ) from `BusinessComponent` template?

Comment: Ohhk. Thank you for clearing.

Comment: @Ganapathi004 yes. No need to emit any output. child and parent uses same object already.

Comment: @Ganapathi004 Yes, objects are ***mutable***. This is good to remember, since in this case you are "lucky" that you want the same reference. But not in all cases you maybe do not want, so it's good to remember :)

Comment: @omeralper It's not working. I changed a property in child and tried to display in parent. Its showing empty.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/WLzZAyFR76N8bOezQ5Oc?p=preview
No it works :)

Comment: @omeralper Sorry! My code is using two different object references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you do not need the two way binding or `@Output`. Since JS objects are mutable, means that reference is same object, BUT, you are doing

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.address = new Address('');
}
```

in child, which initialization I do not also understand, since `Address` (I assume it's a class) has several properties. But if you want to have the same reference you shouldn't do that.

I suggest you use interface for your `Address`, something like:

```
export interface Address {
  houseNo: number;
  street: string;
  village: string;
  city: string;
}
```

also then you can type your object like:

```
address: Address = {}
```

in your parent, or then set initial values to it, but seems you want a clean object in your child.

So remove the following from child `OnInit` and you should be good to go :)

```
this.address = new Address('');
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/B4kRRScCjzEKxrvDAUNS?p=preview)**

Comment: Can you please look at this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/IaK7vdTGpfoA9QTm4Go9?p=preview. I just added a new class without any members and extended App component with it. And it broke everything. The reason I did this is, my Parent extends a class and if I am not initialising the address in child as well, I will be getting the undefined error.

Comment: This is so little information to go on, meaning this empty class `Subscr`, no idea what it's for. And since the class is empty in the plunker there is not much I can do with the plunker either... :(

Comment: From what I can gather, this would perhaps then be use of a shared service instead of using `@Input()`. But as said, it's hard to tell with this information.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't replicate the issue in plunker. I will vote your answer as soon as I get enough reputation.

Comment: Okay :( Well, then I cannot really help further :( But you can also think about the shared service if that would be a better way, I don't know...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146435/discussion-between-ganapathi004-and-ajt-82).

Comment: Hi, what if the object references are different?

Comment: What do you mean with "object references are different"? It sounds like you'd might want to use a shared service instead?

Comment: As I said, the data flow is working even when the error is coming. But because of the error, some other things (router navigation, other components) are getting failed. So If initialize the the object in child component, that will make them different objects. So If possible how I can I proceed for this thing? If not I will go with a shared service as you suggested.

Comment: It is just impossible to help unless you recreate the issue in a Plunker. Because I cannot see the rest of the code. But we could try one thing more... if the error is thrown because of an async issue? We can utilize `ngOnChanges` with the `Input`. Check this plunker were I've utilized a boolean flag `show` and the `ngOnChanges`: http://plnkr.co/edit/FiLMpWIyUk4j5zmjc5Rs?p=preview If this doesn't work, perhaps a shared service would be the way to go most likely :)